# display:flex内の文字の縦位置を中央にできません

Tags: html, css

下記に該当箇所を抜き出します。
こちらのクラスtabBtn内のタブ１～５までの文字を縦位置中央にする方法をご教授ください

**HTML**

```
<!-- ヘッダータブ -->
<div id="tab-1" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-4" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-5" class="switch"></div>
<div class="tabBtn">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">タブ1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">タブ2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">タブ3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">タブ4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-5">タブ5</a></li>
</div>
<div class="tabContents">
    <section id="section-1">タブコンテンツ1</section>
    <section id="section-2">タブコンテンツ2</section>
    <section id="section-3">タブコンテンツ3</section>
    <section id="section-4">タブコンテンツ4</section>
    <section id="section-5">タブコンテンツ5</section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.switch {
    display: none;
}

/* :::::: button :::::: */

.tabBtn {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1px;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tabBtn li {
    flex-basis: 100px;
    background: white;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

.tabBtn li:not(:last-child) {
    /* border-right: 1px solid white; */
}

.tabBtn li>a {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabBtn a:hover {
    background: rgba(205, 92, 92, .5);
}

/* :::::: contents :::::: */

.tabContents section {
    padding: 8px;
    background: white;
}

/* :::::: mechanism :::::: */

.tabContents section {
    opacity: .1;
}

.tabContents section {
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

#tab-1:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-1"],
#tab-2:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-2"],
#tab-3:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-3"],
#tab-4:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-4"],
#tab-5:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-5"] {
    background: indianred;
}

#tab-1:target~.tabContents #section-1,
#tab-2:target~.tabContents #section-2,
#tab-3:target~.tabContents #section-3,
#tab-4:target~.tabContents #section-4,
#tab-5:target~.tabContents #section-5 {
    opacity: 1;
    background: white;
}

/*********************************

*********************************/

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.tabBtn li>a` へ適用している `display` プロパティを `flex` に変更したうえで、 `justify-content`, `align-items` プロパティを用いて位置調整を行うことで、期待する動作が実現出来ると思います。

```css
.switch {
    display: none;
}

/* :::::: button :::::: */

.tabBtn {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1px;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tabBtn li {
    flex-basis: 100px;
    background: white;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

.tabBtn li:not(:last-child) {
    /* border-right: 1px solid white; */
}

.tabBtn li>a {
    display: flex; /* 変更 */
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    justify-content: center; /* 追加 */
    align-items: center; /* 追加 */
}

.tabBtn a:hover {
    background: rgba(205, 92, 92, .5);
}

/* :::::: contents :::::: */

.tabContents section {
    padding: 8px;
    background: white;
}

/* :::::: mechanism :::::: */

.tabContents section {
    opacity: .1;
}

.tabContents section {
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

#tab-1:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-1"],
#tab-2:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-2"],
#tab-3:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-3"],
#tab-4:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-4"],
#tab-5:target~.tabBtn a[href="#tab-5"] {
    background: indianred;
}

#tab-1:target~.tabContents #section-1,
#tab-2:target~.tabContents #section-2,
#tab-3:target~.tabContents #section-3,
#tab-4:target~.tabContents #section-4,
#tab-5:target~.tabContents #section-5 {
    opacity: 1;
    background: white;
}

/*********************************

*********************************/

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-1" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-4" class="switch"></div>
<div id="tab-5" class="switch"></div>
<div class="tabBtn">
  <li><a href="#tab-1">タブ1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2">タブ2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-3">タブ3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-4">タブ4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-5">タブ5</a></li>
</div>
<div class="tabContents">
  <section id="section-1">タブコンテンツ1</section>
  <section id="section-2">タブコンテンツ2</section>
  <section id="section-3">タブコンテンツ3</section>
  <section id="section-4">タブコンテンツ4</section>
  <section id="section-5">タブコンテンツ5</section>
</div>
```

Comment: supa様 期待通りの動きになりました！ありがとうございました！